# Azure NSG is that possible

Tags: azure, vnet, azure-nsg

Is it possible to enable NSG to a cloud service for security purpose? I tried creating a Vnet but I cannot add my NSG to the vnet I created, not sure if thats even possible to do.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/manage-network-security-group ?

Comment: Hi do you have a link for a tutorial how to create cloud service and connect it with a NSG?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign an NSG to a Cloud Service. CLoud Service is the old deployment model under Azure Service Management. I would encourage you to move to an Azure Resource Model design with a VNET and create a SUBNET. You then have two options for an NSG. 1) Create an NSG and assign to your SUBNET or 2) Create a VM, create an NSG and assign the NSG to the NIC of your VM.

Comment: Its been a while since I handled Azure. So Cloud Service is an old deployment, but does the newer deployment(Is that App Service?) support NSG or is that even possible?? Thanks

Comment: NSGs are only available for VNET subnets and VM NIC's. You can create an Access Restriction for your AppService which is basically allow/deny based on IP/subnet [more info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions).

Answer (score 0):

For cloud services you cant attach NSGs. Its old way of deploying apps to VMs. If your using cloud services you have to use [ACLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-acl). Is there any specific requirement of using cloud service? because its a deprecated way of deploying apps. You can use Azure VMs or VM Scale Set for app deployments.